# Turning speaker beep off by alsamixer permanently

Tags: linux, audio, debian, alsa

Debian 7, x64.

I can turn off the beep by reducing Speaker bar volume in alsamixer to 0.

However, after reboot speaker volume in alsamixer is set to 100% again.

How can I turn off speker beep permanently (or possibly save current alsamixer settings in such way that they survive reboot)?

(P.S. I'm using KDE - perhaps it's KDE that messes with it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately answer by user19087 did not work as `pcspkr` module is not loaded by boot on Debian 7 at all (at least on my Dell Vostro laptop) but the ArchLinux wiki did contain the right answer:

```
amixer set 'Speaker' 0% mute
```

After doing `alsactl store` this shut the beep up for good, no beep after reboot.

Comment: For the record I suggest blacklisting both **pcspkr** and **snd_pcsp** (unfortunately my answer was edited, making this less clear). In newer kernels **pcspkr** has been renamed to **snd_pcsp**.

Comment: @user19087: Debian 7 has file:

     % cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base-blacklist.conf 
     # Comment this entry in order to load snd-pcsp driver
     blacklist snd-pcsp. Apparently snd-pcsp is blacklisted by default. It does not show up in lsmod output.

Answer (score 3):

Use the directions at [Disable PC Speaker Beep](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_Speaker_Beep). Basically, as root, run this command:

```
printf "%s\n" "blacklist "{pcspkr,snd_pcsp} > /etc/modprobe.d/beep_blacklist.conf
```

Two important things to note if you blacklist the modules via */etc/modprobe.d/*

- Might need to blacklist both **pcspkr** as well as **snd_pcsp**
- Blacklisted modules can still be pulled in as dependencies of other modules (this can be determined by `modprobe --show-depends mymodule`

Of course there are other methods, such as in X, from Console, using ALSA (as you've already found), etc. If you insist on using ALSA, then `alsactl store` after muting the volume should do the trick.